# How do I create a JavaScript file for each user on the back-end?

Tags: javascript, bash, alexa-skills-kit

So I'm working on a project that provides a front end to users to make alexa skills without coding. Using the ASK-CLI (Alexa Skills Kit) I need to generate and plug data from the front end into some JS files. These files will be hosted on AWS Lambda but need to figure out how to go about setting them up first.

Any info is appreciated.

Comment: You mean AWS S3?

Comment: @StéphaneCharron nope, the JS file created will be given a function name on Lambda and get's called when Alexa makes the request.

Comment: Use CloudFormation or SAM maybe, I don t know the exact requirement to point you in the best direction

Comment: But I don’t think you need one Lambda per user, maybe combine with DynnamoDB